# C# Reading any file in Bytes

Tags: c#, binary, byte, arrays

I have tried many times to open file in "Open File Dialog" just like image
then read it in bytes, then display the source bits using `TextBox`.

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\image1.jpg");
```

**For Ex:**

Read all offsets from `0` to `length` and display file source into `TextBox`
like `001101001101111000001101......`

**Problem:**

I'm beginner in C# and i have seen many functions but i don't know how to put it
in C#.

Comment: SO can't help with problem specified in your post - it is site for coding question, not really life/career advice site. Note that if problem (beginner in C#) is not what you wanted to ask about than both "how to use File.ReadAllBytes" and "convert byte array to binary" have many duplicates which you may want to search for.

Comment: Try getting a book and LEARNING. You will never learn by getting topics answered like this.

Comment: thank you for replay
but the problem that i dont know how to use functions in c# for ex: i don't know how to call the function that user insert it in here

Comment: Then that's the first thing to [learn](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Dissecting-the-First-C-Sharp-Program-You-Created) ...

Comment: i think i must search for these two methods. 1st File.ReadAllBytes & the 2nd convert byte array to binary ... thank you alexei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is better to real all bytes of a file:

```
        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            int len= openFileDialog1.FileName.Length;
            byte[] ATM = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        }
```

Comment: Hello @Pranav
Thank you so much, this is help and i use your code .. it's work but i have a small problem.. when i load a large file like 30MB
the solution stop working and i get this error OutOfMemoryException
please help, Best reagrds

Answer (score 0):

This a way to do it:

```
    private string ToBinary()
    {
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\image1.jpg"
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        int b = 0;
        while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) > -1)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Convert.ToString(b, 2)) automatically converts a number to a binary

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("D:/pqr.jpeg", FileMode.Open);
int a = stream.ReadByte();
```